# How to use CSS API of Grid Component

Tags: material-ui

I'm trying to use the Grid component but I can't find out how to use the CSS API. Ths docs doesn't help me. I just don't get it..

Can someone please help me ?

I know this is not a really good place, sorry, but I can't find any answer anywhere confused

Comment: To be more precise.
I have a Grid of which the direction is the default "row".
But when the breakpoint XS is reached, I want direction to be column-reverse.
I suppose direction-xs-column-reverse in the CSS API can help me, but I can't find out how to use it.

Comment: FYI, I get this answer:
Essentially, you need to wait for [#6140](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/6140). In the meantime, you have to apply custom CSS. We have some [breakpoint mixins](https://material-ui-next.com/layout/css-in-js/#api) to help.
I used it, now working fine :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally, you'd set direction to `row` and [override](https://material-ui-next.com/customization/overrides/#overriding-with-class-names) the `direction-xs-row` class with the name of a class you define (which would set direction to `column-reverse`), but there are no classes exposed for overriding `row` for any breakpoint.

You *could* go the other way, setting direction to `column-reverse` and overriding `direction-*-column-reverse` (for all other breakpoints), but that would be tedious and somewhat insane.

The only way to do this at the moment would be to set the `className` prop to apply some responsive styling via [JSS](https://material-ui-next.com/customization/css-in-js/#jss) and [withStyles](https://material-ui-next.com/customization/css-in-js/#withstyles-styles-options-higher-order-component):

```js
// create a class that will set flex-direction for the xs breakpoint
const styles = theme => ({
  [theme.breakpoints.down('xs')]: {
      responsiveDirection: {
        flexDirection: 'column-reverse',
      },
  },
});

// use withStyles to make the class available via the `classes` prop
export default withStyles(styles)(InteractiveGrid);
```

Then pass your class name, `classes.responsiveDirection` in this example, as the Grid's `className` prop:

```js
          {/* we would normally destructure classes from this.props */}
          <Grid
            container
            className={this.props.classes.responsiveDirection}
          >
```

Check this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/32979jk76) for a working example.